# object of prevstate in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, state

I have object in class state.

```
man: {
name: "John",
wife: [{"children": 2}, {"children": 3}]
}
this.setState(prevState => ({man: prevState.wife[0].children + 1}));
```

I want to plus or minus first wife's children quantity. I use prevState but it doesn't work. why and how can I change this property?

Comment: Please provide your component's code.

Comment: Share your code. Also are you using `prevState` in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook?

Comment: You say it doesn’t work. What doesn’t work about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `man` property before going into `wife` property.
Because `wife` property is inside the `man` property.

```js
let obj = {
man: {
name: "John",
wife: [{"children": 2}, {"children": 3}]
}
}

console.log(obj.man.wife[0].children)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your old state:

```
{
    man: {
        name: "John",
        wife: [{"children": 2}, {"children": 3}]
    }
}
```

And you're returning new state:

```
{
    man: 3
}
```

If you need to preserve same structure of state, the solution can be:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    man: {
        ...prevState.man,
        wife: prevState.man.wife.map((value, i) => (i === 0 ? {
            ...value,
            children: value.children + 1
        } : value)),
    }
}));
```

But such modifications usually easier with [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) [update](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#update) or [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) [over](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over):

```
this.setState(prevState => R.over(
    R.lensPath([`man`, `wife`, 0, `children`]),
    (v) => v + 1,
    prevState,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({man: prevState.man.wife[0].children + 1}));
```

as you are missing state name `man`